# Maven Jetty server plugin password protection

Tags: web-applications, maven, maven-plugin

I am using the Maven Jetty plugin to run my web application. I use `mvn jetty:run` command to start my server that starts hosting my web app. It basically has an HTML page that provides various features by invoking Java servlets. I want to make the built in web-app or my HTML page password protected. How can I do that? Please let me know in comments if any more information is required.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:
 1. Use a security framework like Spring Security (it requires make your app a Java webapp).
 2. Put an Apache Web Server as front-end of jetty and setup security on Apache.

Moreover, if your project is not Java, why do not use only Apache? Jetty is a JSP/Servlet container and it seems you are not using it (only serves HTML).